# Регулярные выражения, и как их правильно использовать?

Tags: python, telethon, re, parse

Моя задача получить сообщение в телеграмм, и прогнать его через фильтр.
Нужно найти в сообщение комбинацию чисел формата 68362|9999999|1|3
Я знаю что в начале всегда 5 чисел, после так же всегда 7, дальше 1 и дальше так же 1 число.

Я реализовал такой код:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def reaction(event):
    chat = await client.get_input_entity(event.message.from_id.user_id)
    message = event.message.message
    filt = re.findall(r"\d{5}|\d{7}|\d{1}|\d{1}", message, flags=re.M)
    if filt:
        print(f"Комбинация поймана!\nДанные: {filt[0]}|{filt[1]}|{filt[2]}|{filt[3]}")

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Но код ловит все сообщения где есть хоть какие то числа, будь то 122121212121121, код просто выведет мне чушь. Я не могу понять как правильно построить фильтр что бы ловить заданную комбинацию.
Так же я пробовал реализовать вот так:

```
\d{5}\w\d{7}\w\d{1}\w\d{1}
```

Но все так же безуспешно

Comment: `|` - интерпретируется как ИЛИ. Экранируйте.

Comment: \d{1} == \d - "{1} соответствует предыдущему токену ровно один раз (бессмысленный квантификатор)". https://regex101.com/r/F8dY80/3

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey а Вы видите где-то использование '|' ?

Comment: @Виктор
В re.findall, а вы видите?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Да, тут согласен - проморгал:) Смотрел последний рег.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил изменив маленькую w на заглавную.
Получил такой фильтр: `\d{5}\W\d{7}\W\d{1}\W\d{1}`
работает без нареканий

Comment: Теперь он будет ловить и такие строки 68362"9999999.1 3

Answer (score 0):

Проблему можно решить просто экранировав [спецсимвол](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#:%7E:text=The%20special%20characters) "|", как сказано в комментариях.

```
import re

message = "68362|9999999|1|3"
#message = "68362999999913"
filt = re.findall(r"\d{5}\|\d{7}\|\d\|\d", message)
if filt:
    print(f"Комбинация поймана!\nДанные: {filt[0]}")
```